# Dismiss NavigationView when Hidden SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

**How can I dismiss a view that I presented with a `NavigationButton` where the `NavigationBar` is hidden.**

I intentionally have hidden the NavigationBar so I can put items on top of the NavigationBar in the center which is not possible by default(only trailing and leading).

My current code is this:

```
NavigationView {
        VStack { 
                ...
                NavigationButton(destination: SignUpView(), isDetail: true) {
                    Text("Account erstellen").bold()
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(minHeight: 40).padding(.top, 0)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                }
                ...
        }
        .navigationBarItem(title: Text(""), titleDisplayMode: .inline, hidesBackButton: true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
```

On SignUp View I have an dismissBtn but without functionality which I want to add now.

Comment: @NRitH the difference is that I've presented it in a NavigationView

Comment: Answer says to use PresentationButton(Text("Click to show"), destination: SomeOtherView()).transition(.slide). Try it, it should to perform popup logic. It will exactly what you need

Comment: I don't want popup animation. I want the navigation one but without the navigation bar

Comment: It is explained in answer that Navigation functionality doesn't work properly. Use PresentationButton instead of Navigation

Comment: But I dont want the popover view all the time. And when I dismiss the view I can't bring it up again

Comment: So wait when the Apple fix that